# jQuery Drag & Drop: Dragging an enclosing element

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to add drag & drop according to this guide

https://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_draganddrop.asp

I have

`CoffeeScript`

```
  $('#topic-list').on 'dragstart', '.topic-draggable', (event) ->
    console.log event
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id)
    console.log event.target
    console.log event.target.id
```

`HTML (ERB)`

```
  <li draggable="true" class="topic-draggable" id="topic_{{{topic_id}}}">
    <a href='<%= topics_path %>/{{{topic_id}}}'>
```

The items are inserted dynamically and `*_id` is replaced by a number. The problem is when I try to drag the `<li>`, then `event.target` is the `<a>` element and the `target.id` is blank.

`Browser console`

```
<a href="/topics/2">
  <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
  <span class="topic-name">Life Span Development</span>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
</a>
```

How do I drag & drop the `<li>` elements, not the `<a>` elements?

I could use `event.target.parent` or some hack, but not sure that is correct. I tried it, but got the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined`.

```js
$('#topic-list').on('dragstart', '.topic-draggable', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", event.target.id);
  console.log(event.target);
  return console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

```css
ul#topic-list {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: white;
        background-color: #20A0D0;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
}
        li {
          list-style: none;
}
          li:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #3DB1E7;
          }

          a {
            padding: 20px 20px;
            display: flex;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
            justify-content: space-between;
          }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul id="topic-list" style="display: block;">
  <li draggable="true" class="topic-draggable" id="topic_1">
    <a href="/topics/1">
      <i draggable="true" class="fa fa-th topic-draggable"></i>
      <span class="topic-name">Introduction to A&amp;P</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li draggable="true" class="topic-draggable" id="topic_2">
    <a href="/topics/2">
      <i draggable="true" class="fa fa-th topic-draggable"></i>
      <span class="topic-name">Life Span Development</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li draggable="true" class="topic-draggable" id="topic_3">
    <a href="/topics/3">
      <i draggable="true" class="fa fa-th topic-draggable"></i>
      <span class="topic-name">Medical Terminology</span>
      <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
    </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

I actually can't create an example because StackOverflow's code editor is giving the error `DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`.

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please?

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I actually can't create a working example because StackOverflow's code editor is giving an error: `DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally got it after much consternation.

`CoffeeScript`

```
  topicDrag = false
  currentTarget = null
  $('#topic-list').on 'dragstart', '.topic-draggable', (event) ->
    li = $(event.target).parent().parent()
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", li.attr('id'))
    li.css('border', '1px dashed red').css('opacity', '0.3')
    topicDrag = true

  $('#topic-list').on 'dragover', 'li', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault() if topicDrag # allow drop, but only for our topics, not random links

  $('#topic-list').on 'dragenter', 'li', (event) ->
    return unless topicDrag
    # browser will call dragleave after dragenter when moving from one <li> to another, turning off the border. fix order.
    currentTarget = event.target # save only the very last target
    setTimeout ->
      # console.log 'dragenter '+currentTarget.nodeName
      $(currentTarget).parentsUntil('#topic-list', 'li').css('border', '2px dashed yellow')
    , 100

  $('#topic-list').on 'dragleave', 'li', (event) ->
    # console.log 'dragleave '+event.target.nodeName
    # when jumping from li > a > span to another, browser calls events in wrong order. clear all.
    $('#topic-list').children().css('border', 'initial')

  $('#topic-list').on 'drop', 'li', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    data = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text")
    # console.log data
    source = $('#'+data)
    # the browser allows dropping on child elements of <li> for some reason
    $(event.target).parentsUntil('#topic-list', 'li').before( source ).css('border', 'initial')
    source.css('opacity', 'initial').css('border', 'initial')
    topicDrag = false
```

`HTML-ERB`

```
  <li id="topic_{{{topic_id}}}">
    <a href='<%= topics_path %>/{{{topic_id}}}'>
      <%= fa_icon 'th', draggable: true, class: 'topic-draggable' %>
      <span class='topic-name'>{{{topic_name}}}</span>
      <%= fa_icon "angle-right" %>
    </a>
  </li>
```